# Rails: validate that all belongs_to are integers?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I use the selectize plugin extensively for letting users select an associated model. Sometimes, their javascript fails and the form tries to submit a String instead of a model ID. Since I have foreign key constraints, this causes a 500 exception. Is there some rails-way to mass-apply a

```
validates :product_id, numericality: true
```

To all `belongs_to` references in all active record models?

Comment: all active record models have a product_id column?

Comment: No, it was just an example, I'm wondering if theres a rails-way to validate all belongs_to *_id columns are integers